# What is the authentication flow when calling Azure Service Bus from console app using Client Certificate with Azure AD App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureservicebus, client-certificates

Using C#, I have created a console application that calls out to Azure Service Bus to send a message, having an app registration setup in Azure AD with a client certificate as the authentication.

I use the azure "ClientCertificateCredential" class for this.

This works.

However, I am unsure of the flow of this and how it works. What is it doing under the hood? How does it add that certificate to the request? Is it different from a TLS certificate? Is it just 1 call? Or is it doing anything with making 1 request, then getting a token returned, to make another? etc.

I have not managed to find a flow diagram of this.

Here is the test code for reference:

```
string tenantId = "xxx";
string clientId = "xxx";
string clientCertPath = "mykey.pem";
string queueName = "xxx";
string fullyQualifiedNamespace = "xxx.servicebus.windows.net";

TokenCredential credential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientCertPath);
var client = new ServiceBusClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, credential);

ServiceBusSender sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

ServiceBusMessage busMessage = new ServiceBusMessage("test");

sender.SendMessageAsync(busMessage).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Client Certificate Authentication** is a mutual certificate based authentication, where the client provides its Client Certificate to the Server to prove its identity. This happens as a part of the SSL Handshake

**ClientCertificateCredential** Class enables authentication of a service principal (App Registration) in to Azure Active Directory using the client certificate that is assigned to it's App Registration

**TokenCredential** Class obtains the access token from the ClientCertificateCredential provided

This access token will be used to access Azure Service Bus

For more information on Client Certificate Authentication, you can refer this blog: [Client Certificate Authentication - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/client-certificate-authentication-part-1/ba-p/324623)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can I get this straight in my head then. The exact same certificate used for M-TLS, is the certificate used for auth with AAD to access Azure Service Bus in my scenario? So, 1 certificate to do both? And the auth part of it is just done very early in the call stack - TLS handshake - before the HTTP stack?

Comment: The certificate which is uploaded to Azure App Registration client certificate is used to access the Azure Service  Bus in your  scenario

Comment: Yes I understand that the public certificate uploaded to Azure is the one that will be used for auth. My question was...in an M-TLS scenario, is the certificate that is used for the client side of M-TLS, the same one used for auth on Azure?

Comment: Client certificate authentication is just a single call